# An error in simple C++, but can't figure out why

Tags: c++

I have my code like this, and I have 
1>test.obj : error LNK2019: "void __cdecl iceCreamDivision(int,double)" (?iceCreamDivision@@YAXHN@Z) 외부 기호(참조 위치: _main 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
1>D:\download\CS161\Debug\CS161.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1개의 확인할 수 없는 외부 참조입니다.
sorry it's in Korean, but it's saying there's an external symbol and the error is on the first void method.
This code is straight from a textbook, and I wonder why this isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void iceCreamDivision(int number, double totalWeight);

int main()
{
    int number;
    double totalWeight;

    cout << "Enter the number of customers: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Enter weight of ice cream to divide (in ounces): ";
    cin >> totalWeight;

    iceCreamDivision(number, totalWeight);

    return 0;
}

void iceCreamDivison(int number, double totalWeight)
{
    double portion;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        cout << "Cannot divide among zero customers.\n";
        return;
    }

    portion = totalWeight/number;
    cout << "Each one receives "
        << portion << " ounces of ice cream." << endl;
}
```

Comment: You really should get an English compiler (or whichever part need to be English) (even just [an online one](http://ideone.com/) could work) if you wish to ask compiler-error-related questions on [so].

Comment: Check the given links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410798/c-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274838/visual-studio-fatal-error-lnk1120

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993316/fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is typo in your code

you declared

```
void iceCreamDivision(int number, double totalWeight);
```

but you defined

```
void iceCreamDivison(int number, double totalWeight)
```

Notice the difference between `Division` and `Divison`.
See learning C++ also help you with English language.

Comment: haha thanks! I'll fix it. This is pretty embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `iceCreamDivision` but define a different function with the misspelt name `iceCreamDivison`. Add the missing `i` to the definition.